# jquery script refuse to execute again after making one round

Tags: jquery

I have set of few thumbnails, each time user click on thumbnail I show big picture on the middle, and animate/hide thumbnail, delete if from the top and insert it on the end of thumbnail set. But after making full round - clicking on the first picture again - script doesn't execute anymore. The script:

```
$(".loadMainPhoto").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();      
   var $this=$(this).children(":first");
   var html="<div class='filmStripOuter'id='div_"+$this.attr('id')+"'>"+$("#div_"+$this.attr('id')).html()+"</div>";    
   var parent=$("#div_"+$this.attr('id')).parent();

   $("#div_"+$this.attr('id')).animate({
      opacity: 0.25,
      height: 'toggle'
   }, 500, function() {
      $("#div_"+$this.attr('id')).remove();
      parent.append(html);
   });
```

I'm not sure if my explanation is enough, I'll provide  other info as needed. Any help appreciated.

[edit]
Thanks to Stefan and Mark it is fixed right now, the problem was that I try to match element that was added after page was loaded, and bind does't work then. The solution is to use the same element (not new one) or to use live() http://api.jquery.com/live/ you can see how it works on my playground ;) http://papiez.me

Comment: can you please post the relevant html structure?

Comment: also check the console, if there's an error javascript stops running. it could be the case that the first run doesn't produce any error but the second time it does

Comment: Thanks to Stefan and Mark it is fixed right now, the problem was that I try to match element that was added after page was loaded, and bind does't work then. The solution is to use the same element (not new one) or to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you can see how it works on my playground ;) [papiez.me](http://papiez.me)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are modifying the DOM and should have a look at http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot... As jquery description said: "This new element also matches the selector, but since it was added after the call to .bind(), clicks on it will do nothing."

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a trailing `});` is that part of the issue or is this a mispost?

Why are you inserting a new div?

`"<div class='filmStripOuter'id`...

Seems like you should be capturing the original (first) then re-inserting it, not creating some new wrapper with an entirely new id (with "div_" prepended to old ID.

Comment: Missing trailing is mistype when I copied it. You are right if I move it instead of creating new one it works. And like Stefan point out this is the same problem, bind doesn't work with elements that are created after page is loaded. Anyway both solutions work, thanks a lot ;)